# VBA, inline array

Tags: arrays, vba

Looking to create an inline array in Visual Basic for Applications

Something like this would be cool:

```
Dim a() as Integer
set a = {1,2,3}
```

In Java, this would be the equivalent functionality:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
```

Also, bonus points if you can tell me how to find its length afterwards (without needing to hard code it, as all the examples my Googling have uncovered)

(please don't tell me to Google it. I normally don't use vb, and I'm discovering that every result for a vb question on Google is answered terribly. ex, hard coding values)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Dim a() As Variant
Dim Length As Integer

a = Array(1,2,3)

Length = UBound(a,1) - LBound(a,1) + 1
```