# Hardcoding a simple 4X3 array

Tags: excel, vba

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784592/vba-inline-array) which demonstrated nicely how to hard code a 1D array.  However I am trying to hard code a 2D array and my various attempts are failing.

This is what I have tried so far

```
Points = Array(Array(2, 1, -2), Array(8, -7, 8), Array(-1, -10, 5), Array(5, -3, 3))
Points = Array(2, 1, -2 ; 8, -7, 8 ; -1, -10, 5 ; 5, -3, 3)
Points = Array(2, 1, -2 : 8, -7, 8 : -1, -10, 5 : 5, -3, 3)
Points = Array((2, 1, -2), (8, -7, 8), (-1, -10, 5), (5, -3, 3))
```

Is there a way to do this or do I have to go and assign each entry individually?

ie I am trying to avoid the following

```
 Points(1,1) = 2
 Points(1,2) = 1
 Points(1,3) = -2

 Points(2,1) = 8
 Points(2,2) = -7
 Points(2,3) = 8

 Points(3,1) = -1
 Points(3,2) = -10
 Points(3,3) = 5

 Points(4,1) = 5
 Points(4,2) = -3
 Points(4,3) = 3
```

Comment: Can you  try explaining **what you try accomplishing**? Do you only want playing with such an array? A 2D array can be simple extracted from an Excel Range: `Dim arr`, followed by `arr = Range("A1:C4").Value` . This is a 2D array (4 rows x 3 columns). You can obtain it through iteration also, or in other methods, but if you cannot definite the filling rule and want random numbers as 5, -3, 3 it is not possible to write a code line and fill an array having 12 elements... Can you define an algorithm based on what to be the array filled? If yes, I will try helping you to accomplish what you need.

Comment: @faneduru I was looking for a quick way to drop in some test points that I could easily edit within the VBA editor.  Basically its the x,y,z, of 4 test points..

Comment: 'Points = Array(Array(2, 1, -2), Array(8, -7, 8), Array(-1, -10, 5), Array(5, -3, 3))'. This is the closest you will get in VBA.  Points needs to be declared as a Variant 'Dim Points as Variant'.  The values assigned to Points will create an array of arrays (sometimes known as a jagged array).  You reference each item in the array using the nomeclature Point(x)(y).  e.g. Point (x) returns an array, (y) selects the item in the returned array.

Comment: I still do not understand what you want accomplishing, sorry... Where these "test points" to be? Are they abstract entities? Can you edit your question and show us pictures (if not something editable) with your (ipotetic) initial situation and the wished result, too?

Comment: @FaneDuru  They are the coordinates for points in 3D space Pt1 (2,1,-2)  so Pt1 has an x of 2, a y of 1 and a z of -2.  I am feeding these test points into a function to determine if the function does what its supposed to do.  I just pop in the test point at the start of the function so I don't have to step through the rest of my program.  Once I verify the function is work, I will pass an array of 4 points for processing.  For now I was just looking at a quick way to manually have all the data in the function with out passing anything.

Comment: @freeflow thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: @freeflow put that in as an answer and stress the dimming of the array and I will mark that as the answer.

Comment: So, you need a jagged array. I mean, an array of arrays containing three elements. Is that understanding correct? If yes, what problem does your first tried line code? How do you want extracting each jagged array element? @freeflow explained above. In order to return the first element of the first array you should write `Debug.Print Points(0)(0)`. The second element of the first array will be `Points(0)(1) and so on...

Comment: @ForwardEd - fyi posted an alternative late answer creating a 1-based 2-dim array by a one-liner; feel free to upvote if helpful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA does not offer support for initialising arrays at the point of creation with value other than the default 0/nothing.

The simplest approach for creating small arrays is to use the Array method.

e.g. for a 1 Dimensional array

```
Dim myArray as Variant
myArray = array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Arrays with more than one dimension can be achieved by nesting the Array statements.

```
Dim myArrayUniform as Variant
myArrayUniform = Array(Array(2, 1, -2), Array(8, -7, 8), Array(-1, -10, 5), Array(5, -3, 3))
```

When creating an Array by nested Array statement you get an array of arrays, otherwise known as a jagged array.  Jagged arrays are different from a normal multidimensional array in that they have a slightly different nomenclature for accessing individual items.  Its also reasonable to note that the declaration below is perfectly legal for a jagged array

```
Dim myArrayUneven as Variant
myArrayUneven = Array(Array(2,  -2), Array(8), Array(-1, -10, 5), Array( 3))
```

Individual items of a jagged array are accessed using one set of brackets for each level of Array statement.

```
myArray(x)
MyArrayUniform(x)(y)  ' NOT myArrayUniform(x,y)
etc.
```

Why is this nomenclature used?  myArrayUniform is declared as a 1 dimensional array each item of which is itself an array.  Therefore to access any individual item we first select the item in the initial one dimensional array e.g. myArrayUniform(x).  This returns an array in its own right for which we then select the item we wish e.g.(y). Hence myArray(x)(y).

Another 'feature' that should be noted is that variables declared as Variant can contain an array.  Consequently the variable declaration for an array declared using the Array statement does not require brackets provided that the variable is declared as Variant.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a loop:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub mkArr()
    Dim Points(4, 3)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim v, w
    
v = Array(2, 1, -2, 8, -7, 8, -1, -10, 5, 5, -3, 3)

k = 0
For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 3
        Points(i, j) = v(k + i + j - 1)
    Next j
    k = k + j - 2
Next i
        
Stop
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Arghh You can DIM Points (4,3) instead of Points (1 to 4, 1 to 3) .  I did not know that!  THANK FOR THAT ALONE.  still running through the loop and looking at this K value.  In the back of my head since we are just breaking up a list with this method.  change `v(k+i+j-1)` to simply `v(k)` and then change k=0 and then place k=k+1 in the line above assigning the point value as a counter.  Still running this through my head.

Comment: @ForwardEd That is just a shortcut because I have `Option Base 1`, because I wanted the `Array` to come out as Base 1.

Comment: I actually have my code set up with option base 1.  So this is a great learning point for me.  what I am working on is a self project for me working with a lot of 3D basic geometry.  As a result i am playing with matrix operations so I wanted my arrays counting from 1

Comment: I did not realize j would take a value of 4 after completing its 3rd loop,  The k formula you are using makes more sense now.  Having said that I still prefer the more direct counter above points of k=k+1.

Comment: @ForwardEd Yup, there are many ways of constructing the nested loops.  You could even do a `For...Each` type of loop and increment `i` and `j` each time through.

Answer (score 1):

**Creating a 1-based 2-dim array by a one-liner**

Defining a jagged array as in OP allows to apply a mostly unknown approach via a one-liner ~> `[2]`:

- just use the `Application.Index()` function with the given `points` array as first argument and
- pass two zero arguments eventually (instead of indicating precise row/column indices).

```
   ... = Application.Index(points, 0, 0)
```

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    '[1] define an array of arrays (aka jagged array)
    Dim points: points = Array(Array(2, 1, -2), Array(8, -7, 8), Array(-1, -10, 5), Array(5, -3, 3))
    '[2] create a 1-based 2-dim array
    points = Application.Index(points, 0, 0)    
End Sub
```

**...results in the following array**

```
1-based 2-dim array points(1 To 4, 1 To 3)
   * Row 1 ~>  2|  1|-2
   * Row 2 ~>  8| -7| 8
   * Row 3 ~> -1|-10| 5
   * Row 4 ~>  5|- 3| 3
```

*e.g. points(3,2) = -10*